# Looking for an assisted reading/translation program or some other kind of aid

Tags: discussion

I am trying to read a novel in Japanese, now i have never done this before. I am fairly good with kanji and can get by with most manga as long as there isn't too many because of the pictures help lead me in the right direction to remember the translation. i am having a bit of a problem with reading a book however. its set in a fantasy type world with demons magic etc and a lot of weird kanji show up. Is there some convenient way/program to help look up certain parts of what i am trying to read quickly? i have pdf versions as well as picture versions of the book. I guess i would like some kind of assisted version of a pdf or w.e reader. i know theirs a good program for Vn's that lets u just click on individual kanji to look up there meaning etc. any such thing forbooks/managa?

Comment: I'm not trying to be sarcastic, but if you have PDF versions couldn't you just copy the kanji from the PDF into an online dictionary?

Comment: Most defiantly but this is super inconvenient especially if your unsure what the word is or you have multiple items. being able to left click on a kanji and have a program list all possible readings is well way faster than copy goto website paste read options maybe go back and get a couple more characters re-search etc.

Answer (score 2):

KanjiTomo sees to work pretty well it can handle pictures as well as pdfs and other document types. basically left click on what u want to be added it will auto pick a number of characters after which u can easily reduce or increase it gives several possible translations massive time saver!